# Правильно ли написать "c 16 лет по 23 года"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, числительные

Правильно ли написать "c 16 лет по 23 года"? Или как будет грамотнее сочетать "лет" и "года" в этом случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно написать так:

> С 16 до 23 лет (с шестнадцати до двадцати трех лет).

Другое дело, если период действительно начинается с лет, а кончается годами и наоборот:

> С 16 лет до 21 года (с шестнадцати лет до двадцати одного года).

Таким образом, стоит просто писать подходящее слово — года или лет — рядом с числительным. Также обратите внимание, что лучше использовать предлог *до*, а не *по*.